# imagettfbbox() in Apache PHP

Tags: php, linux, apache, gd, apache-config

I have a php Web-based app that uses the imagettfbbox() function. This app has been hosted on IIS but is getting moved to an Apache server. The imagettfbbox() function has a fontfile parameter. On IIS I've used 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Verdana.ttf' for this paramete. I don't know what path to use on the Apache server. I've tried various ones where I've found font directories but none seem to work. What URL should I typically use for this on Apache?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to refer to the font file like this

> /usr/fonts/fontfile.ttf

Comment: The problem is in knowing what directory to point to. The example you gave doesn't exist on my server. I've found various directories that contain .ttf files but none of them seem to satisfy the imagettfbbox() function.